# Can I get a visa on arrival to Port Dickson, Malaysia?

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, visas-on-arrival, sea-travel, malaysia

I am a UK citizen and am cycling from Indonesia to the UK. I want to take a boat from Dumai, Sumatra to Port Dickson, Malaysia.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get a visa on arrival at this port?

Also, would this visa be a 90-day visa?

Answer (score 1):

It should be no problem.

As a UK citizen, [you only need a stamp on your passport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Malaysia#Visa_policy_map). Any immigration officer can do that and there is certainly one in Port Dickson

And yes: it will be 90 days

Comment: I've never been to Port Dickson (I took ferry from Dumai to Malaka and Klang) and can not find confirmation there is an immigration check there. But I doubt they let ferries full of Indonesian passenger in if there is no officier to check/stamp their visa